# Switch off WebStorm HTML Parent Tag Tree Colors

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How do I turn off the automatic highlighting of parent HTML tags in **WebStorm**? It's like it's Christmas! I'm using v2019.2.

It's terribly distracting. Take a look for yourself:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance**, turn **Enable XML/HTML tag tree highlighting** off